# How should we handle dormant questions with problems?

Tags: discussion, migration, tags, old-questions

After posting [two](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45555/retag-request-or-possibly-untag-request-sofaq-official) [questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45575/is-the-sofaq-proposed-tag-special) about `sofaq-*` tags earlier today, I decided to go on a small cruft cleanup spree.  Naturally, that led to... another question.

What should we do about questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898612/how-can-i-link-to-a-specific-answer)?  It belongs on meta, and shouldn't really be tagged `sofaq`, but it's also been sitting idle for over nine months.  Should it be flagged for migration and retagged, or just ignored?  Doing the former would be right thing to do (technically), but would involve work for mods and bump stale questions.  Doing the latter would be wrong, and would be a backdoor endorsement for cruft buildup.

If it were just one post, I wouldn't be asking, but I'm not about to flood the front page/moderator inboxes with several dozen unless the community okays it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Flag for moderation attention.
- Bring the problem to Meta for us to vote it as belongs on Meta.
- Edit to bump at the front page for it to gain attention if it still belongs on SO.

Comment: +1 - Flagging is definitely the best option because it stays in the moderator queue until one of us handles it.  Bringing it here to meta is almost as likely to work.  Editing to bump or quietly voting to migrate could easily go without notice and be ineffective.